# Автоматизация с открытой вкладкой Puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Можно ли настроить автоматизация на Puppeteer с уже открытой страницей браузера?
К примеру на сайте есть форма,в которой я уже ввела данные,и он должен обратиться к селекторам.
И как получить селекторы если у них нет id и два одинаковых класса

Comment: По правилам стоит задавать один вопрос на проблему, так что про селекторы лучше спросить отдельно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`puppeteer` общается с браузером при помощи [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). Чтобы этот протокол работал, нужно запускать браузер со специальным ключом командной строки, указывая порт для протокола:

```
chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

После этого можно подключаться и получать/передавать данные так:

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

const browser = await puppeteer.connect({
  browserURL: 'http://localhost:9222', // Используем тот же порт, что и при запуске.
  defaultViewport: null, // Если нужно открывать страницы из puppeteer с привычным вьюпортом.
});

try {
  const pages = await browser.pages(); // Все открытые вкладки браузера.
  const page = pages.find(
    page => page.url() === 'https://example.org/' // Если нужно найти вкладку по URL.
  ) || pages[0]; // Если нужна просто одна открытая вкладка.

  const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const { title } = document;
    return title;
  });
  console.log(data);

  browser.disconnect(); // Отключаемся, вместо закрытия браузера.
} catch (err) { console.error(err); }
```